# How can I make my cursor be on the same line as the prompt when reading input?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that either prints output, or prompts for input, with content being printed out character-by-character, typewriter-like:

```py
import time
import sys

def printy(text):# This is for print function
  for character in text:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)
  
def inputy(text):# This is for input function
  for character in text:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)
  value = input()  
  return value
```

But each time I use `printy()` or `inputy()`. I get output that runs the prompt and the output together without any newline:

```
HelloWorld!Python
```

I know that I could use `\n` after the text but doing this repeatedly for every print and input is painful. My goal is that what should I do to the defined functions to that each time I use this function it makes them leave a space after each time the function has been called but not with the `\n` because then the input is something like this (with the cursor at the `_` location):

```
Why is this asking for input down with "/n":
_
```

What I *want* is this (again, with the `_` representing the cursor):

```
Like this for print
And like this for input: _
```

I tried using the code by adding `\n` to each print and input, but then it starts the input from the down part of the input. See "Problem with \n" to understant properly.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i76723369/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Woodford How do I post errors without pics? on stackoverflow?

Comment: not sure I fully understand your question but one of your error messages says "/n" which is not a newline. "\n" is a newline.

Comment: @IndieMultiCraft You should post them as text, just like the code.

Comment: @julaine look i tried printing \n as string but it would think its new line so i had to write it like /n.

Comment: @IndieMultiCraft to actually print \n, you need to escape the backslash, like so: \\n. Alternatively you can use an r-string.

Comment: @IndieMultiCraft please accept the answer from Ξένη Γήινος or explain why it does not solve your problem.

Comment: Here's the summary.  You want an automatic newline after a `printy` (just like `print`), and you do not want an automatic newline after the `inputy` prompt.  Right?  That's exactly what the first answer below does.  And there are no "errors" here.

Comment: @IndieMultiCraft, I edited your question to show you how to demonstrate your problem without screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add a newline after the end of the animated string, it is really simple. You have several options, it all just requires you to do `sys.stdout.write('\n')` at the end.

Method one: explicit call

```
def printy(text):
    for char in text:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Method two: just concatenate the input with a newline and loop through the concatenation.

```
def printy(text):
    for char in f'{text}\n':
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

Result:

```
In [532]: printy('Hello, World!'); print('Python')
Hello, World!
Python
```

Answer (score -1):

you are probable adding space between end = "".try this-

```
import time
import sys
def printy(text):
  # This is for print function
  for character in text:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)
  print("\n",end="")

  
def inputy(text):# This is for input function
  for character in text:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)
  value = input()
  print("\n",end="")  
  return value

printy("hello world!")
print("this is my terminal")
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for print here is picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12VNMrM5nx_9AZUJwvrhrgnur_naJCobD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: don't put the space between end=""

Comment: show me the screenshot of your whole program

Comment: @DarkStar, please don't ask for screenshots -- we spend most of our time trying to convince people _not_ to provide them :), as in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122); insofar as this program is textual in nature, unless you're asking for a video/animation, all of its output -- like its source code -- can be shown as monospaced ASCII.

Comment: (that said, while I haven't downvoted this answer myself, I'm definitely not upvoting it in its current state because "use this code" doesn't explain _why_ the provided code is correct; our purpose is to teach people how to write better programs in the future, not just to hand them fixed replacements).

Comment: sorry about that,i didn't know  about this because i am new here